# REST api complex type parameter doesn't have properties populated

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api, fiddler

I'm trying to call a REST api via POST and passing in my parameter as a json array (username and password). The object is instantiated, but the properties are not.  Where am I going wrong?

```
[HttpPost]
public AuthenticationResult Authenticate([FromBody]LoginModel login)
{
    try
    {
        if (login == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Username and Password are required for authentication.");

        AuthenticationService authService = new AuthenticationService();
        AuthenticationResult result = authService.IsAuthenticated(login);

        if (result.IsAuthenticated)
            return result;
        else
        {
            return new AuthenticationResult()
            {
                IsAuthenticated = false,
                User = new User()
                {
                    UserId = login.Username
                }
            };
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return new AuthenticationResult()
        {
            IsAuthenticated = false,
            Message = ex.Message
        };
    }
}
```

And I'm testing from Fiddler...

I'm set to "POST", url: htp://localhost:2134/api/login/authenticate

Request Headers:

```
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:42761
Content-Length: 73
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
```

Request Body:

```
{
"Username": "ganders",
"Password": "myHashedPassword"
}
```

Edit: According to [this article](http://bitoftech.net/2013/11/25/implement-http-actions-post-put-delete-web-api/), it would appear as though I have everything structured correctly...

Edit2: LoginModel

```
[Serializable]
public class LoginModel
{
    public string Username { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }

    public string AccessToken { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to remove the [Serializable] attribute from my LoginModel class.

Comment: Alternatively, you could have added the attribute `[JsonIgnore]` to your `AccessToken`.